# intellij 13 weird scala error: many unresolved symbols

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am facing a weird issue in intellij 13, as shown here

[image]

Many of the methods are not resolved. Is it about scala version? But I do already have this as 2.9.2, as shown here[image].

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and [`File > Invalidate Caches`](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/cleaning-system-cache.html) helped.

Comment: i tried to "invalidate caches and restart", it still shows the same error. So the errors are like "cannot resolve symbol format" on String, "Application does not take parameters" on scala.collection.immutable.List, etc. These are so weird, and I don't know where they originate.